# Loading 50.000 items in a table creates unexpected timeline results

Tags: performance, google-chrome, polymer, google-chrome-devtools, elm

I'm testing the performance between Elm and Polymer by using the Chrome Timeline. I have written a table in each language/library and I'm filling this with 100, 1000, 5000, 10.000 and 50.000 items. I measured the loading, scripting and rendering time.

I've come across a result in my measurements which I didn't expect.

In the images below(in the links) you can see the (Polymer) results for 10.000 and 50.000 items. For the 10.000 items a lot of rendering takes place, but for the 50.000 items there is almost no rendering and a lot of scripting... Can someone explain this to me?

[10.000 items Polymer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2ClX.png)

[50.000 items Polymer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK8q4.png)

In the table below the render time in `ms` is set out for Elm and Polymer.

```
╭───────╥────────────┬─────────────╮
│       ║     Elm    │   Polymer   │
╞═══════╬════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 100   ║   17,98    │    11,7     │
│ 1000  ║   92,44    │    95,32    │
│ 5000  ║   570,98   │    571,24   │
| 10.000║   1115,12  │    1138,08  │
| 50.000║   0,42     │    0,72     │
└───────╨────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: There might be a hardcoded limit for lazy rendering.

Comment: @wOxxOm the table does load completely...

Comment: Without seeing code I don't even know what we're talking about. As for lazy-rendering, it means invisible (off-screen) items are rendered only when needed.